Keyboard for Input in TableView
Currently my spreadsheet has cells for data entry and if they are too low the keyboard overlaps them. I'm trying to make the table slide to the top when the keyboard appears and the input field remains visible. However, it is not possible to make this happen simultaneously with the appearance of the keyboard. Help please
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Mixed Cells"
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        // Заполнение данными
        for i in 1...20 {
            data.append(.text("Static Text \(i)"))
        }
        data.append(.input("Name", "Enter your name"))
        data.append(.input("Email", "Enter your email"))

        // Настройка таблицы
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(TextCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextCell")
        tableView.register(InputCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "InputCell")

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil
        )

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil
        )

        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
              let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else {
            return
        }

        let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        tableView.contentInset = .zero
    }

Besides, it seems that the keyboard animation is slower than tableView.contentInset. I will be grateful for your help.
you can see the code here - https://github.com/AlexDolm/testUI

This question is similar to: How can I make a UITextField move up when the keyboard is present - on starting to edit?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In the referenced duplicate, see this specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52290543/20287183. Though it hardcodes the duration time. Instead, use the same duration as the keyboard animation.

Don't even bother implementing keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide. Just make a constraint pinning the bottom of your view to the top of the keyboard, and all the right stuff will happen automatically.
